# Cannot dynamically change background color/font color using var() function within the body tag (react/css)

Tags: css, reactjs

I’m super new to coding and I’m trying to include dark mode functionality for my app. However, as it says on the tin, the var() function within the body tag isn’t working and I’m not sure why.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ToggleDarkMode from './ToggleDarkMode';
import './index.css';

function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false)

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode)
  }

  return (
    <div data-theme={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"}>
     <ToggleDarkMode darkMode={darkMode} toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} />
     <h1>Hello</h1>
     <h2>world</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


export default function ToggleDarkMode({darkMode, toggleDarkMode}) {
 

  return (
    <>
    <input
      type='checkbox'
      checked={darkMode}
      onChange={toggleDarkMode}
    />
    {darkMode ? '' : ''}
  </>
  )
}
```

This is all the css code there is.

```
:root {
  --bg-color-light: #fff;
  --font-color-light: #424242;
  --bg-color-dark: #161625;
  --font-color-dark: #e1e1ff;
 
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--font-color)
}

[data-theme='light'] {
  --bg-color: var(--bg-color-light);
  --font-color: var(--font-color-light)
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
  --bg-color: var(--bg-color-dark);
  --font-color: var(--font-color-dark)
}
```

The colors within the body will change if I just remove var() and manually enter a color. It also works dyanamically if I change the body tag to a * selector. I'm not quite sure what's going on. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to check what element has that data- attribute and also to see exactly what CSS is being set and by what?

Comment: Maybe because you're using `--bg-color` but while you declared `--bg-color-dark` and `--bg-color-light`, not `--bg-color`